# Ext.Panel display error using custom css borders

Tags: css, border, panel, extjs3

I have created a JSfiddle to let you show the issue...
http://jsfiddle.net/mrgamer/u3Z48/

element.width of **x-panel-body** is incorrectly calculated, in the example above it's set on 340px, instead to CORRECTLY show the borders i've set should've been set to 338px!

Screenshots to clarify even more:

**How it is:**

[image: How it is]

**How it should be:**

[image: How it should be]

I understand this is a really tiny 'issue', still i don't know how to correct it, it's annoying to have such display errors in a overused component like Ext.Panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem is enough defining the width in the style config, like this:

```
var panel1 = new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Inner Panel',
    height: 300,
    style: {width: '350px'},
    border: false,
    cls: 'panel_class',
    bodyCssClass: 'body_border'
});
```

It's not as clean as possible, but i think it's a decent solution to the ExtJS miscalculation!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
.x-panel-body .body_border{
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 1px;
}​
```